# Traer valor del select y dejarlo marcado por GET

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

Buenas estoy haciendo la edición de pedidos y traigo los datos a través de GET. Hay un campo en la tabla que se llama `Iduser` que es el usuario que a realizado el pedido.

Luego para editar el pedido me sale un select con todos los usuarios que tengo en la BD.

```
<select id="select2-1" value="" class="form-control selectSegundo" name="select2-1" style="min-height: 38px;">
   <option value="0">Seleciona un cliente</option>
   <?php
     $resultisa = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Usuarios");
     mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
     while($resia = $resultisa->fetch_array()) {
   ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $resia['IdUsuario'] ?>"><?php echo $resia['Nombre'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Me gustaría que en este select me saliese seleccionado el usuario que viene a través de GET, pero teniendo la posibilidad de cambiar el usuario por otro.

Alguna idea??? Gracias

Comment: en la etiqueta option añades selected si el usuario coincide <?php if ($resia['IdUsuario'] == $_GET['idUsuario']) {echo selected;} ?>

Comment: Gracias @Carmen hay que tener en cuenta que es un select buscador, es de una libreria llamada select2

Comment: no debería afectar, no modificas ni el valor ni el contenido de la opción

Comment: Así de este modo si que me funciona <br> <option value="<?php echo $resia['IdUsuario']; ?>"<?php if($resia['IdUsuario'] == $res['Iduser']){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php echo $resia['Nombre'] ?></option>

Comment: Esa es la idea, con el nombre con el que tengas la vatiable. Estupendo :)

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer un condicional y comparar cada valor que venga de la tabla Usuarios.
Supongamos que el valor del GET lo recibes así:

```
// No está sanitizado el GET es un paso que debes hacer, pero por cuestiones de explicación:
 $IdUsuarioGet = $_GET["IdUsuario"]; 

<select id="select2-1" value="" class="form-control selectSegundo" name="select2-1" style="min-height: 38px;">
 <option value="0">Seleciona un cliente</option>
   <?php
   $resultisa = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Usuarios");
   mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
   while ($resia = $resultisa->fetch_array()) {
   ?>       
    <option value="<?php echo $resia['IdUsuario'] ?>" <?php if ($IdUsuarioGet == $resia['IdUsuario']) {
    echo "selected='selected'";} ?>><?php echo $resia['Nombre'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
```